# Python Flask + Javascript : return image and display in web page

Tags: javascript, python, image, flask

Possibly a silly problem but i couldn't solve it alone. 
I am running a Flask application and one of the functions allows to take a picture from a camera on a remote raspberry pi zero, then display it on the web page with JavaScript.

All I am getting seems to be the EXIF data of the picture, e.g. (from Chrome's dev console 'Elements'):

```
<img src="����d Exif etc.">
```

Here is the Flask route:

```
@app.route('/_getShot', methods=['GET'])
def takePicture():

 os.system('ssh pi@192.168.3.40 python3 singleShot.py &')
 sleep(6)
 #with open("static/shot.jpg", 'rb') as shot:
 #     return flask.send_file(shot.read(), as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='shot.jpg', mimetype='image/jpeg')
 #     return flask.Response(shot.read(), mimetype="image/jpeg")
 shot = 'static/shot.jpg'
 return flask.send_file(shot, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

I've left a couple other methods I've tried, commented out (same result).
For now, the singleShot.py script (on the remote RPI zero) takes a picture then scp's it on the main RPI in my_app/static/, until I can properly return the image in Python without needing to physically write it on disk.

And the html/javascript:

```
<div>
<button class="button" id="picture">Shot</button>
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#picture').click(function () {
 $('#picture').text("Working...");
 getShot();
 });
 });

 function getShot() {
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/_getShot",
     contentType: "image/jpeg",
    }).done(function(data) {
    var shot = document.createElement("img");
    shot.src = data;
    document.getElementById('image').appendChild(shot);
    });
    };
</script>
<div id="image"></div>
```

I've tested multiple methods and syntax , but unless I set the image source as 'static/shot.jpg', I'm only getting that EXIF data.
I'm not sure whether the issue is in the Python or JavaScript code. Anyone can help?

Comment: Ok quick edit: it's not the exif data, it's rather the image as a string. I tried to handle it with IOBytes and a couple other methods, but to no avail..

Comment: You need to base64 encode the image data before sending to HTML.  img tag supports src="base64string"

Comment: how would the base64string be placed in this case?

Comment: <img src="data:img/png;base64string"/>, please help with this?